# Problema de tamaño con FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema con mi el calendario de FullCalendar. Lo inicializo y todo bien, pero al cargar me muestra los números de la columna derecha cortados. Se me arregla cuando cambio de mes, ya los números se me muestran correctamente, pero necesito que desde un inicio se muestren correctamente. ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

[image: FullCalendar]

Este es mi código html:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Calendario</h5>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success animate__animated animate__fadeIn" id="regresar">
                                <i class="bi bi-send"></i> Regresar
                            </button>
                        </div> 
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Este es mi javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        locale: 'es',
        headerToolbar: { left: '', center: 'title', right: 'prev,next', },
        titleFormat:{ year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
    });
    calendar.render();

});
```

Y este es mi Css:

```
.fc .fc-toolbar-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.fc .fc-col-header-cell-cushion {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```